# Bookmarklet: run JS command after page is loaded

Tags: browser, internet-explorer, automation, bookmarklet

I build quite a lot of bookmarklets to automate my every day's work. Now I faced a problem: I would like (by clicking on a bookmarklet) to open a page in web browser (I use Internet Explorer 8) and apply some specific operation on its interface.

The web application is old and does not provide some advanced option like table filtering. I have this functionality already written, now I would like to open a web app and apply my JS code by one click on bookmarklet.

So I would like 3 steps to by done by one click:

1. Open some webpage.
2. Wait for webpage to be fully loaded.
3. Run some JS command, let say `alert('test');`

I tried few times, but it seems impossible to me. So I would like to be sure: is it do-able?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Sathya - Internet Explorer 8, unfortunately :)

Comment: Might be possible if you load the page in a frame.

Comment: @DanielBeck - interesting idea, I've never thought about it. I will check and let you know! Cheers!

Comment: @DanielBeck - totally forgot about SOP policy. I am not allowed to run JS action in iframe because of different origin of "bookmarklet scope" and the iframe I've created.

Comment: Right. So there's basically no solution to this question then, because any solution would break at that policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have this functionality already written, now I would like to open a web app and apply my JS code by one click on bookmarklet.

Use a remote script via `window.open` and `window.opener`:

```
  /* Web App */
  <script>
  window.open('remote.html')
  </script>

  /* remote.html */
  <script>
  window.opener.onload = function(){}
  </script>
```

Add the script tag to the Web App via the bookmarklet, then it will do the rest.

**References**

- [Working with Windows: Referencing the Opener](http://www.webreference.com/js/tutorial1/opener.html)
- [Parent<=>Child Window Bidirectional Connection](http://www.webreference.com/js/tips/000610.html)